# GroupPadding changes order of columns in series

Tags: highcharts

When I added  the following property to my chart:

```
columns: {
    groupPadding: 1.05
}
```

It reversed the order of the columns in the series.  Any ideas on why this may be occurring or an alternative to adding padding between the columns of a series?

Comment: Can you show some demo ?

Answer (score 0):

The group padding is given is axis values, so in a categorized X axis, a group padding of 1.05 wouldn't make any sense. Values from 0 to 1 would make sense, where 0 renders the columns tightly packed (if pointPadding is 0), and 1 renders them as thin lines.

For adding padding, also consider api.highcharts.com#plotOptions.column.pointPadding .